# Error when using unserialize in php?

Tags: php

```
$info='a:1:{s:10:"2G Network";s:22:"GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900 ";}';
$info1 = unserialize($info);
print_r($info1);
```

When run code in firebug get error:

```
Notice: unserialize() [<a href='function.unserialize'>function.unserialize</a>]: Error at offset 0 of 65 bytes in...
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Provide correct serialized data.... that always helps fix unserialize() problems: a:38 is defining an array with 38 elements

Comment: Your serialized data is broken. It should be an array with 38 entries, it is an array with 1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

`$info='a:38:{s:10:"2G Network";s:22:"GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900 ";}';` is not properly serialized.

The format for an array is as follows:

a:*number of items*:{*collection of elements*};

You one element in your array (2G Network => GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900). All the rest is fine, and the following unserializes properly:

```
a:1:{s:10:"2G Network";s:22:"GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900 ";}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use utf8_encode and utf8_decode..
like..

$str = utf8_encode($str); 

$str= unserialize($str); 

$str= utf8_decode($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is help to resolve your problem :

```
<?php

$info = serialize(array('2G Network','GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900'));
(or)
$info='a:1:{s:10:"2G Network";s:22:"GSM 900 / 1800 / 1900 ";}';

$info1 = unserialize($info);
// Show the unserialized data;
print_r($info1);
?>
```

For Your [Functional Reference](http://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/unserialize.php) click this for example.